# Handling exception in pytest fixture and pytest.fail vs assert in general

Tags: python-3.x, pytest

Consider you have something like the following:

```
import pytest

@pytest.fixture
def foo_fixture():
    assert x == 1, "X is not 1"
    if x != 1:
        pytest.fail("X is not 1")


def test_foo():
    assert x == 1, "X is not 1"
    if x != 1:
        pytest.fail("X is not 1")
```

Can someone please shed light on differences between raising errors via `pytest.fail` vs `assert`,
in both contexts - inside `pytest.fixture` or inside regular test function.

What is the difference, what is more right\common to do in each case?

Thank in advance

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The biggest difference is that pytest.fail() can't be caught and assert can:

for example - this test is going to pass:

```
def test_assert():
    try:
        assert False
    except:
        pass
```

and this test is going to fail:

```
def test_pytest_fail():
    try:
        pytest.fail('failed')
    except Exception:
        pass
```

Other than that I don't think there are more major differences because they both raise an AssertionError.

Anyway, I would suggest you use this library https://pypi.org/project/assertpy/ for more cleaner and readable assertions.

**** **EDIT:** ****

Guess I was wrong:

pytest.fail() can be caught by catching the specific exception **Failed** or just '**BaseException**.

So - they both are ways to raise exceptions but from some reason **Failed** does not inherit from the generic **Exception** type.
so pytest.fail() raises **Failed** exception and not **AssertionError**

Comment: And any difference case for if I'm in `pytest.fixture` or regular test function for above usages?

Comment: same differences - although I don't tend to raise assertion errors during fixtures, for that I use regular exceptions, why? because that way I'm able to distinguish whether the failure is because of a bug in the product or just undesired state I got into.
and also, some reporting frameworks like Allure looking at assertions and other types of exceptions in a different way and presenting them in a different way